# Defining variables esp32

Tags: c++, arduino, conditional-statements, case, esp32

i am trying to figure out a way in esp32 to have (a list) for lack of better terms, that i could call upon as a variable input. I have a void playwav(); function. I want to use a global variable to define the file that should be played. ie playwav('alarm'). I had a case switch setup but was using the a b c method. As my code is growing (next step is going to add 71 new wav files), i am quickly realizing that method will no longer work. I have been told to do an array but for the life of me no matter what ive read i just cant grasp how to do it nor call upon the files by name. Does anyone have advice on what i should do? Any help is much appreciated.

This is what i currently have.

```
void playWAV (char effect, int bg1248_general_volume)
{
  Serial.println("Entered playWAV");
  switch (effect)
  {
    case 'a':
      file = new AudioFileSourceSD("/wav/alarm.wav");
      break;

    case 'b':
      file = new AudioFileSourceSD("/wav/alarmhigh.wav");
      break;

    case 'c':
      file = new AudioFileSourceSD("/wav/alarmlow.wav");
      break;

    case 'd':
      file = new AudioFileSourceSD("/wav/error.wav");
      break;
  
    case 'e':
      file = new AudioFileSourceSD("/wav/error1.wav");
      break;
  
    case 'f':
      file = new AudioFileSourceSD("/wav/noread.wav");
      break;
      
    case 'g':
      file = new AudioFileSourceSD("/wav/noreadings.wav");
      break;
      
    case 'h':
      file = new AudioFileSourceSD("/wav/normalrange.wav");
      break;
      
    case 'i':
      file = new AudioFileSourceSD("/wav/warning.wav");
      break;

    case 'j':
      file = new AudioFileSourceSD("/wav/warninghigh.wav");
      break;
      
    case 'k':
      file = new AudioFileSourceSD("/wav/warninglow.wav");
      break;
      
    case 'l':
      file = new AudioFileSourceSD("/wav/startup.wav");
      break;  

      case 'm':
      file = new AudioFileSourceSD("/wav/startup.wav");
      break;      
      
      case 'n':
      file = new AudioFileSourceSD("/wav/update.wav");
      break;  
      case 'o':
      file = new AudioFileSourceSD("/wav/startup_dev.wav");  
      }

float volumeGain = ((float)bg1248_general_volume / 100.0) * 39.0;
  Serial.print("volumeGain:");
  Serial.println(volumeGain);
  id3 = new AudioFileSourceID3(file);
  out = new AudioOutputI2S(0, 0); // Output to builtInDAC
  out->SetPinout(12, 0, 2);
  out->SetOutputModeMono(true);
  out->SetGain(volumeGain);
  wav = new AudioGeneratorWAV();
  wav->begin(id3, out);
```

However because I used the alphabet im going to run out of cases very very soon. I want to be able to call for a specific wav file anywhere in the project preferably like **playWAV(filename)** or something similar.

I call the function(file) like this (example condition)

```
if((ns->sensSgv<=cfg.snd_alarm) && (ns->sensSgv>=0.1)) {
// red alarm state
// M5.Lcd.fillRect(110, 220, 100, 20, TFT_RED);
Serial.println("ALARM LOW");
M5.Lcd.fillRect(0, 220, 320, 20, TFT_RED);
M5.Lcd.setTextColor(TFT_BLACK, TFT_RED);
int stw=M5.Lcd.textWidth(tmpStr);
M5.Lcd.drawString(tmpStr, 159-stw/2, 220, GFXFF);
if( (alarmDifSec>cfg.alarm_repeat*60) && (snoozeRemaining<=0) ) {
    playWAV('a', 100);
```

'a'=case 100 = volume.

Alan, this is what I currently had in my enum, i was following a tutorial but doubt i did it right. even if i did i was getting errors saying i had duplicate cases when i don't.

```
EDIT:
```

The condition is set using this:

```
if((ns->sensSgv<=cfg.snd_alarm) && (ns->sensSgv>=0.1))
```

and if you notice at the bottom there is:

```
if( (alarmDifSec>cfg.alarm_repeat*60) && (snoozeRemaining<=0) ) {
    playWAV('a', 100);
```

The a corelates to the case A in the switch case. shown above. currently all the places that use the playWAV function are manually specified.

Comment: Please show what you have as a [mre] and describe more about what you want to achieve. Describing what you think would help is OK, but also spend some words on what you want to do with any solution proposed here.

Comment: Sure, give me a few minutes, I will update the original post.

Comment: I understand that you have a switch case implementation which achieves what you want, but predicatbly will be too clumsy for many more files. I think just showing that would be sufficient, if not perfect. If it works now, somebody will be able to show you how to use an array for achieving the same just more elgantly in the context of many files.

Comment: I just updated the main post, is that sufficient ?

Comment: You dropped my previous edit. That is your choice, but please double check that it is what you wanted to do.

Comment: How would you like to select among 100 files? A single letter will not be sufficient. I assume that the `char` is coming from user input somehow. Please also show that part, I feel it will be needed to change that.

Comment: I dropped an edit? not sure how i did that, that was not intentional.

Comment: Just create an array of filenames then your switch statement becomes `file = new AudioFileSourceSD(filenames[effect]);`, is difficult to know why this isn't the obvious solution without seeing a [mre]

Comment: I thought it was not intentional. No insult. Please click on the "edited ... ago" next to Alans Avatar to see previous versions. You can pick up my phrasing and learn something about the formatting Alan applied.

Comment: @AlanBirtles You are basically right, but I suspect we need a change on the source of `effect` to cater for more than 100 choices...

Comment: I just updated the post to put in an example of where im calling it and the full code. I will check that previous version right now

Comment: Ok i did see the edit Alan made. my apologies for overlooking it

Comment: So just change effect to a number (or even better an enum) then you can do `playWAV(0, 100);` with the filenames array?

Comment: Take some time to look at Alans and my edits. Read https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help Users here are quite understanding about the dificulties of our editor. Do not worry. But if you spend a little time reading on how to format, it will be much easier for you to convey your info and problems. Please also read about making a [mre]. It is a little less straight forward in case of environments as the arduino, but also well worth it, for making good questions.

Comment: Alan, I was looking at an enum as from what i read you can still call by names, i tried it and i couldn't get it to work, ill post what I had if i still have it as a new post instead of a comment.

Comment: @AlanBirtles With no intention to insult, I think the definition and filling of an array of char sequences might be what is beyond OPs level right now. Also, maybe, robustly and cleanly getting an input other than a single letter... especially if represented by an enum.

Comment: Note sure how to write another post should i just update the main post real quick?

Comment: I tried adding it here, didnt want to work right. Here it is on pastebin. https://pastebin.com/FhUahQDs

Comment: From the code you posted where the function `playWAV()` is called, it doesn't tell us what is the selection condition for playing 'a' instead of 'g' and your didn't show us that part. Another question is how do you get 'a'?  Without knowing the selection condition, it is hard to suggest how to modify your code.

Comment: Just updated the post for you. tldr the 'a' is from the switch case and manually inputed by me on the function. there is no automatic selection.

Answer (score 1):

My understanding was using the alphabets in switch case will ran out soon because of large no. of files (>26). So, I implemented the logic using enum first and below is the complete code.

```
#include<stdio.h>

enum soundEffects {
    alarm,
    alarm_high,
    alarm_low,
    Dev_startup,
    error,
    error1,
    noread,
    noreadings,
    normalrange,
    startup,
    startup_dev,
    update,
    warning,
    warning_high,
    warning_low,
};

void playWav (enum soundEffects effect, int paci_volume)
{
    //Serial.println("Entered paciplay_day");
    //printf("Entered paciplay_day\n");

    switch (effect)
    {
        case alarm:
            //file = new AudioFileSourceSD("/wav/alarm.wav");
            printf("/wav/alarm.wav\n");
            break;

        case alarm_high:
            //file = new AudioFileSourceSD("/wav/alarmhigh.wav");
            printf("/wav/alarmhigh.wav\n");
            break;

        case alarm_low:
            //file = new AudioFileSourceSD("/wav/alarmlow.wav");
            printf("/wav/alarmlow.wav\n");
            break;

        case error:
            //file = new AudioFileSourceSD("/wav/error.wav");
            printf("/wav/error.wav\n");
            break;

        case error1:
            //file = new AudioFileSourceSD("/wav/error1.wav");
            printf("/wav/error1.wav\n");
            break;

        case noread:
            //file = new AudioFileSourceSD("/wav/noread.wav");
            printf("/wav/noread.wav\n");
            break;

        case noreadings:
            //file = new AudioFileSourceSD("/wav/noreadings.wav");
            printf("/wav/noreadings.wav\n");
            break;

        case normalrange:
            //file = new AudioFileSourceSD("/wav/normalrange.wav");
            printf("/wav/normalrange.wav\n");
            break;

        case warning:
            //file = new AudioFileSourceSD("/wav/warning.wav");
            printf("/wav/warning.wav\n");
            break;

        case warning_high:
            //file = new AudioFileSourceSD("/wav/warninghigh.wav");
            printf("/wav/warninghigh.wav\n");
            break;

        case warning_low:
            //file = new AudioFileSourceSD("/wav/warninglow.wav");
            printf("/wav/warninglow.wav\n");
            break;

        case startup:
            //file = new AudioFileSourceSD("/wav/startup.wav");
            printf("/wav/startup.wav\n");
            break;

        case update:
            //file = new AudioFileSourceSD("/wav/update.wav");
            printf("/wav/update.wav\n");
            break;
    }
}

int main()
{
    //below are the 3 ways of calling your playWav() function
    //1 - using direct numbers
    //this will throw compilation error when compiled using cpp compilers
    for (int i = 0; i<14; i++)
    {
        printf("enum value: %d\n", i);
        playWav(i, 50);
    }

    //2 - directly calling using the enum
    playWav(startup, 100);

    //3 - Just another way of calling
    enum soundEffects sound;
    sound = error;
    playWav(sound, 100);
    return 0;
}
```

Also, I implemented this same logic using double array's. Please do find it below. This uses the name of the file as a parameter so altogether we can eliminate the use of switch statement.

```
#include<stdio.h>

void playWav (const char *filename, int paci_volume)
{
    //Serial.println("Entered paciplay_day");
    printf("Entered paciplay_day\n");

    //file = new AudioFileSourceSD("/wav/update.wav");
    printf("/wav/%s\n", filename);
}

int main()
{
    const char list_of_files[][25] = { "startup.wav", "update.wav", "warning.wav", "alarm.wav" };
    for (int i = 0; i<4; i++)
    {
        printf("name: %s\n", list_of_files[i]);
        playWav(list_of_files[i], 50);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Please omit my *printf* statements which I used for debugging. I hope this is useful.

Comment: This looks perfect! so to play a file i could simply go playWAV(alarm, 100)? If so that is exactly what i was looking for. Second question if i add more files, is it as simple as adding another case block and then updating the list at the top with the new file name?

Comment: Yes, if you add more files you just need to update the above enum and switch case statement as needed.

Comment: Perfect!!!! Thank you so much! this is 100% spot on for what i was asking for.

Comment: Hello kite, I was trying to implement the enum you provided. I am getting stuck on an error.  argument of type "int" is incompatible with parameter of type "soundEffects", am i doing something wrong here?

Comment: the line in question is this one              playWav(i, 50);

Comment: Please try using `playWav(startup, 100);` instead of direct int types as cpp compiler (in my case - g++), also throws the same error for directly using `i (int)`.

Comment: im not even using it yet and it throws the error preventing me from composing....should i comment out and see if it breaks anything?

Comment: In the enum logic `main()` function, there are 3 ways to call your `playWav()` function. You have to use either of those 3 logic's. So, please use the second one i.e., `playWav(startup, 100)`.

Comment: Hello again, I went through my project and changed the playwav arguments into the format you specified. when i upload i get stuck in a boot cycle. the crash log indicates it received a null value....im not sure how to resolve that.

Comment: Is there anyway you can show me the code or collaborate? I don't think the above logic would cause an infinite loop. Also it would be great if more info is provided on the error.

Comment: Sorry! I just saw this. I had to move back to an older version of my code (power went out IN the MIDDLE of building, hence the code got currupted. I am now back at the point of adding in your enum (still very thankful for!). I am getting the following errors upon build time.

Comment: C:/Users/Administrator.MYTDS/Documents/PlatformIO/Projects/bg1248/src/BG1248.ino:167:12: warning: enumeration value 'startup_dev' not handled in switch [-Wswitch]
C:/Users/Administrator.MYTDS/Documents/PlatformIO/Projects/bg1248/src/BG1248.ino: In function 'int main()':
C:/Users/Administrator.MYTDS/Documents/PlatformIO/Projects/bg1248/src/BG1248.ino:242:22: error: invalid conversion from 'int' to 'soundEffects' [-fpermissive]
         playWav(i, 50);
                      ^

      ^

Comment: I am using the method you suggested example here:

 if(cfg.snd_warning_at_startup) {
         yield();
  delay(500);
  if (!playing) {
    playing = true;
    playWav(startup_dev, 100);


So im not sure what to do.

Comment: sorry darn character limit hehe

Comment: Fixed the error about the int, just commented it out and it built but now my device is in a reboot loop as it cant play the file in the enum